# Circular button that resizes with window size

Tags: css, resize

I'd like to make a circular button (div works too) and put it in the centre with a diameter of 20% of the height of the window. This I can do, but the button will become oval if the window isn't exactly square (I'd like the width and height to be the same - a perfect circle).

```
.circle {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000
}
```

Hardcoding a pixel value isn't much of an option as it wouldn't resize based on the window. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, there isn't such thing as `20% of the window` if you don't want it to become oval. It's either 20% of the width or 20% of the height.

Comment: Edited my question. I would like 20% of the height.

Comment: What type of element is your circle? img? div?

Comment: Edited my question. It's a div. It could also be a button.

Comment: you could add a square blank image inside and use it to stretch your div. With your div absolutely positionned, you'll be able to set the img's height accoringly to window's height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to achive this; with and without JavaScript.

### The JavaScript method

Here's a simple demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/3ZJz3/).

HTML:

```
<div class = "circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
}
```

JavaScript (uses jQuery, but it isn't necessary):

```
function upd() {
    var h = $("body").height();
    $(".circle").height(h / 5);
    $(".circle").width(h / 5);
}
upd();
window.onresize = upd;
```

### The non-JavaScript (CSS) method

For a CSS-only solution, you need to use the fact that all `padding` values are calculated relative to the element parent's `width`, not `height` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-padding-top)). Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/JnB6q/).

HTML:

```
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "main">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}
.wrapper {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 100%; /*1:1 ratio*/
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; /*fill parent*/
    border-radius: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    /*I wanted it to look good :)*/
    font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Assuming I can guarantee that w/e browser sees this will support `calc()`, how can I do it with pure CSS? As far as I can tell (I just googled it) `calc()` only does arithmetic and can't get the page dimensions.

Comment: @Andrew I was wrong :( Updated answer with a method similar to Dpolehonski's.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to achieve a perfect circle without using any JS, it lies in the specifications definition for padding percentage. When the padding is applied as a percentage it is applied as a percentage of the objects **width**, which means if you set width and height to 0, and give the object a padding of 20% you'll end up with a circle occupying 20% of the available width. You'll need to get creative to get things inside the circle though.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        width:80%;
    }
    .square
    {
        width:0%;
        height:0%;
        padding:20%;
        position:relative;
        left:25%;/*Position central*/
        border-radius:100%;
        margin:auto;/*Position central*/
        border:1px solid #000000;   
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yep, although it [doesn't lie in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-padding-top).

Comment: Actually, you'll need a padding of `10%` to emulate a `width`/ `height` of `20%`. But the idea is is good and there are no worries about support in this case.

Comment: @Ana Hmm. I had to use `:after` pseudo-elements, actually.

Comment: **Note:** This will only work to make the circle `20%` of **`width`**, since the `padding` is calculated relatively to `width`.

Comment: @Abody97 It doesn't matter. Every browser that supports `border-radius`, which is essential here, also supports pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to add `min-height` and `min-width` property to that circle with same value.

```
.circle {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```